# Play sound during MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, video-capture

I'm creating a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app where I'd like to record some video footage (without audio) while playing an audio file through speakers.

I tried doing that using a MediaElement by setting the source and playing on the MediaOpened event. This does work as long as MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync() is not running.

When I try to record the video and hit the play button, the sound is not audible. Interestingly, if I stop the video recording while the audio file should still be playing, I actually can hear the last part of the audio.

I assume the StartRecordToStorageFileAsyc() is blocking audio, but can this be disabled somehow?

Comment: Hello, one month after, I think that it's not possible, however, if you found a solution can you post it please ?

Comment: haven't found a solution yet - I also don't think it's possible atm

Comment: Oh that's not cool since in other platforms you can do that, I hope it'll be possible in the new Windows, since a lot of things are changing.

Comment: it seems that you can play sounds while recording when you have headphones plugged in.

Comment: thomas, I think but i'm not sure that with the new Windows 10 API it is possible to do it since new changes has been made to the MediaElement class, I don't have much time to check it out for you, if anyone can find out if that's true please update this question :)